# lazyloading for ng2-pdf-viewer in Angular 14

Tags: pdf, lazy-loading, angular14, pdf-viewer, ng2-pdf-viewer

I am loading a pdf contains 16 pages using ng2-pdf-viewer updated version(9.1.5) in Angular 14.
I want to use lazy loading for this PDF, what are the concepts I need to do.

I used the thumbnail image before loading PDF, once the pdf is loaded, the thumbnail image is hidden and the pdf should be visible. Is this the correct method or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the correct way, set up "after-load-complete" event as shown in the [official docs](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer#after-load-complete).

Alternatively, you can use "on-progress" event in order to show progress bar.